# How to extract server information

Tags: powershell, server, wmi

Objective: How to extract server information?

For each server name listed in servers.txt, I would like to get the following information (in this format):

Server name, IP Address, OS name, Total Physical Memory, Processors, each drive letter and size, System Model

Comma separated and new line for each server.

Below is my PowerShell code. Can your guys give a hint on why this does not work? Also why I get an error with `New-Object` statement?

```
foreach ($ComputerName in (Get-Content -Path .\servers.txt)) {
  $HashProps = @{
    'tHostname' = Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    'tIP' = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($computername)
    'tOS' = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption
    'tMemory' = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | foreach { "$("{0:n2}" -f ( $_.Sum/1GB ) )" }
    'tcpu' = Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | Select-Object name, numberofcores
    'tDisks' = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | foreach { "$($_.DeviceID) $("{0:n2}" -f ( $_.Size/ 1GB ) )" }
    'tsysmodel' = Get-Wmiobject Win32_computersystem | Select-Object model
  }
  New-Object -TypeName psObject -Property $HashProps |
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -Append .\output.csv
}
```

I am open for a other approach, if this is easier.

Comment: You need to define "does not work" and explain what error you get from `New-Object`.

Comment: @alroc: It was something about that `New-Object` were unexpected. If I does not run the two last lines, no error appear. Then running the two last lines works fine. However, I do not get the out for all the servers and the format which I seek. I hope this help a little.

Comment: Please do not paraphrase errors. Post them *exactly* as they are. If there is interpratation needed, we'll be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that each of those lines actually return what you want?

I just threw this into the ISE and it works fine:

```
$f = gwmi win32_computersystem | select name,model,totalphysicalmemory
$hash = @{
    'name' = $f.name
    'model' = $f.model
    'memory' = $("{0:n2}" -f ( $f.totalphysicalmemory/1GB ) )
}
New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $hash | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -Append .\test.csv
```

Also, if you want the properties to appear in a specific order in the CSV, it will take some additional magic, otherwise they're put in alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit pimped, maybe this will help you:

```
$Servers = Foreach ($ComputerName in (Get-Content -Path .\Servers.txt)) {
    $CS = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $OS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $PM = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $PR = Get-WmiObject Win32_processor -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $LD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $IP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($ComputerName)

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ServerName = $CS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        IPAddress  = $IP | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
        OS         = $OS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption
        Memory     = $PM | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum | foreach { "$("{0:n2}" -f ( $_.Sum/1GB ) )" }
        CPU        = $PR | Select-Object Name, NumberOfCores
        Disks      = $LD | foreach { "$($_.DeviceID) $("{0:n2}" -f ( $_.Size/ 1GB ) )" }
        Model      = $CS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Model
    }
}

$File = Join-Path $env:TEMP 'Ouptut.csv'
$Servers | Export-Csv -Path $File -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
Start-Process $File
```